# Rebuilding a collapsed empire

Tags: society, science-fiction, empire-building, interstellar-travel, hibernation

I am making a galaxy where humans have reached an age where everything is peaceful and paradise, like spanning thousands of planets. However, a disaster happened that caused all the worlds to be separated and chaos happened on every world causing them to regress in technology and culture.

My protagonist is someone who wakes up from his stasis along with a massive crew in his city sized ship by its AI in which all the technology is stored in.

How should he rebuild the empire where almost every one has become hostile as even with their better equipment they still can get overwhelmed

Comment: David Weber, *Dahak* trilogy -- [*Mutineers' Moon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutineers%27_Moon) (1991), *The Armageddon Inheritance*, *Heirs of Empire* (2003). After the fall of the Fourth Imperium, the *Utu*-class starship *Dahak* remains the only survivor of the once mighty fleet. Unfortunately, she is crewless (long story) and decides to continue masquerading as Earth's moon while she ponders what to do next. 50,000 years later she makes up her mind and begins to recruit a new crew in order to rebuild the Imperium. Available online at http://baencd.freedoors.org/ (long story why).

Comment: How far have the people regressed and what level of technology do they now have available?

Comment: It all depends on the world but there are mini empires trying to fight each other for resources, they once had weapons that created blackholes and the standard issue guns were rifles that could destroy matter,Tanks that was fast as cars and medical tech that could revive the dead as long as the body was intact enough but now the stuff you find is kinetic weapons and the rare laser rifles,There used to be Agumented Reality implanted in the body but now its just something like smart phones as Most of the tech is salvaged. The Protag has acess to the full library but cant make them all

Comment: The standard war ship back than was about 5000 meters but now they can only make them a 1000 meters max with only a fraction of its capable destructive power, however even so these can still gang up on the Protags ship and destroy it, the protags ship has a factory inside it and can produce things on the go but will need bigger facilities to make most of the heavier stuff, Most tech the modern galaxy use are excavated stuff to produce outdated designs in which they try to improve as much as possible

Comment: People are afraid of AI since it had a hand in the collapse so they try to avoid use of it as much as possible but the AI was not really the cause as it was made to do so by someone, immortality was possible  and if people got bored they would simply use rebirth to experience life anew again so the modern galaxy only has slightly better medical tech like ours with some regressed gene tech and robotic prosthetics, there is a "warp" system in which the empire enters a network to instantly get anywhere but there is also the standard FTL engine which takes months to travel around the galaxy

Comment: This takes place a millenium after the collapse, most scientist would rather hunt for tech than make new ones so there is a form of stagnation going on, people live in terrible conditions and is mostly under the foot of the tyranical empires and only the lucky few get acess to the nice stuff, food production was once so easy you could just make a pill that tasted really good for you and would keep you feed for the day but now its all made in these giant factories that churn out bio mass shaped into bars(this only an example from the many planets so each one can vary)

Comment: do you mean unified them back under the original empire custom or recreate/inhabited back the original empire tradition/technology in different new planet/the original capital?

Answer (score 1):

**Very slowly**.  Presumably the empire is very large, and it will depend on the exact nature of the empire and of interstellar travel.  Presuming that interstellar travel is not something that can be done in a lifetime without stasis then we have a very different type of empire from one with a warp drive.

Ultimately, your planets need a reason to want to come back together.  I find it nearly impossible to believe that every single system hates every single other system equally.  It is probably far more reasonable to assume that each system has its own set of enemies, its own set of "friends we don't talk to anymore", and its own set of systems that they've almost never interacted with.  This is actually a lot like how it is on Earth right now.  Countries within a single geographical area usually either trade with each other or invade each other far more than countries well outside of their geographical area.  Sometimes, countries basically have nothing to do with each other other than either vague threats or vague assurances that we're cool with you.  For instance, Canada and Uruguay don't have a world-shatteringly important alliance, but they tolerate each other and are probably friendly.

More likely your individual planets will either start running out of stuff or will just want something that their neighbours have, but won't want to fight a war to get it.  Perhaps they have no resources, or are just tired of war.  Your ship will have to find these neighbours and start the relationship back up.  Eventually, other systems realize that the relationship they have is beneficial and want to join in.  Probably with talk of the "Old Empire" and the glory days.

Throughout this there will likely be other alliances, or systems who either weren't touched by the calamity or recovered quickly, who want to test and/or take things by force.

Answer (score 1):

**Step by step, with buy-in from the worlds included.**

1. Your protagonist needs intel.  He or she needs to know what is going on in various worlds of the former Imperium.
2. These worlds will be in different situations.  If there is a world of stone age farmers, a ship full of tech will probably just be scary.  You want a world in which things have slid technologically but not so far they have forgotten what tech is.  You do not want a stable government because they will see no reason they should not stay in control and take possession of the tech.  You want a world with chaos and warfare where your ship can show up, make peace and be hailed as rescuers.
3. Ideally this chosen world is one of the lynchpins of the original imperium, because the people will likely have a culture which lends itself to this sort of endeavor.  Once your chosen starting world is stabilized and uplifted, it will send missions to nearby worlds.  Missions might start with health care, or food, or clean water.  After this initial show of benevolent intent, these worlds will then be invited to partner in a confederation of trade and mutual protection.

Answer (score 0):

*In the future there will, unfortunately, always be those living in poverty.*

As human society deteriorated, the salvation army wasn't a thing anymore, charity was forgotten. With the protagonist and their massive crew, they start a campaign to help the unfortunate.

The journey was long and grueling, as heart breaking stories were revealed and tragic deaths woke up the minds of many. They made peace between families and communities. But in the world as a whole, little has changed, as people continued to scoff and ignored their actions.

Then, it happened... One big act of kindness, an indescribable scene made at the verge of death. It influenced billions, and broke through the layers of ice that had accumulated in the people's hearts.

The world stopped to listen to what the protagonist had to say...

Little by little, civilization began to progress, and leading them was the voice of the protagonist, that was broadcasted all over the galaxy